# How to find a file and include another file into it?

Tags: php

I'm using a plugin that updates alsmost evert week, and when that happens it overrides every work that I've done. I welcome  the updates but not when it overrides my inputs. I'm trying to keep my inputs in seperate file and have a code in place that will find the pluging file and include my inputs as a file. That way nothing will break, my inputs and the updates will both be intact. my code looks like below.

```
$useThis = 'search-processor.php';

$putHere = "um-actions-members.php";

file_put_contents($useThis, $putHere, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to find a file and include anothe file into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you will not parse the PHP commands, you only include what is inside the php file

```
$useThis = "search-processor.php";
$putHere = "um-actions-members.php";

// get the content of $putHere
$fileContent = file_get_contents($putHere);

file_put_contents($useThis, $fileContent, FILE_APPEND);
```

To parse the PHP commands you need to go inside the `$useThis` and use the `include` command, like

```
include("um-actions-members.php");
```

Comment: going inside and using the include method doesn't work because it will be overridden when the plugin updates.